# Arrange Pandas dataframe columns in horizontal manner with customized column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows

```
Actual  Expected
F00000191U  F00000191U
2022-09-30  2022-12-20
0.546437    0.546437638135
F00000191U  F00000191U
2022-09-30  2022-12-20
F00000191U  F00000191U
2022-09-30  2022-12-20
0.546437    0.517306000000000
F00000QAXU  F00000QAXU
2022-02-28  2022-07-31
```

The alphanumeric characters are unique and they are keys and the date and the decimal values are related to the alphanumeric entity ID. For e.g. F00000191U has the date 2022-09-30 and a value of 0.546437 which is the actual value and aside are the expected values displayed. I have derived the mismatch from a data frame and I am getting the result as this. I wanted this to be displayed in a vertical format as follows.

```
Actual Entity ID | Actual start date |Actual Value |Expected Entity ID  |Expected date |Expected val
F00000191U       |2022-09-30         |0.546437     |F00000191U          |2022-12-20    |0.546437638135
```

Is there any way I can achieve this format with the help of a generic method? I am new to Pandas so just trying to search for a way for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Annotated Code

```
# Is alphanumeric?
mask = df['Actual'].str.isalnum()

# Create supplementary index to identify block of rows
# associated with each precceeding alphanumeric id 
df['idx'] = mask.cumsum()

# identify different columns within each index block
df['cols'] = df.groupby('idx').cumcount().map({0: 'entity id', 1: 'start date', 2: 'value'})

# Reshape in wide format  
result = df.pivot(index='idx', columns='cols')

# flatten the multiindex columns
result.columns = result.columns.map(' '.join)
```

#### Result

```
    Actual entity id Actual start date Actual value Expected entity id Expected start date     Expected value
idx                                                                                                          
1         F00000191U        2022-09-30     0.546437         F00000191U          2022-12-20     0.546437638135
2         F00000191U        2022-09-30          NaN         F00000191U          2022-12-20                NaN
3         F00000191U        2022-09-30     0.546437         F00000191U          2022-12-20  0.517306000000000
4         F00000QAXU        2022-02-28          NaN         F00000QAXU          2022-07-31                NaN
```

Comment: I don't see the column names in the list. Can you elaborate how you have achieved the result?

Answer (score 0):

The neat answer by Shubham didn't work for me so I tried a naive solution:

```py
import re

def process(df):
  actual_entity = None
  actual_date = None
  actual_value = None
  expected_entity = None
  expected_date = None
  expected_value = None
  for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row[0], str) and row[0].startswith('F'):
      if actual_entity or actual_date or actual_value:
        yield {
            'Actual Entity ID': actual_entity,
            'Actual start date': actual_date,
            'Actual Value': actual_value,
            'Expected Entity ID': expected_entity,
            'Expected date': expected_date,
            'Expected val': expected_value
        }
        actual_date = None
        actual_value = None
        expected_date = None
        expected_value = None
      actual_entity = row[0]
      expected_entity = row[1]
    elif isinstance(row[0], str) and re.fullmatch(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', row[0]):
      actual_date = row[0]
      expected_date = row[1]
    elif isinstance(row[0], float):
      actual_value = row[0]
      expected_value = row[1]
  yield {
          'Actual Entity ID': actual_entity,
          'Actual start date': actual_date,
          'Actual Value': actual_value,
          'Expected Entity ID': expected_entity,
          'Expected date': expected_date,
          'Expected val': expected_value
    }
```

Then you just need to apply the generator:

```py
pd.DataFrame(process(df))
```

Comment: Where should I pass the df in iterrows? In the method as a parameter?

Comment: I am not getting the value populated in any of the cells with this code.

Comment: Yes, for me this worked because I defined `df` globally for the purpose of this exercise